# Regular expression to extract one word before a given word from a word list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I want to extract a word for the question- who ate the apple. Like the string is "Ujjwal ate the apple." So it should extract the word 'Ujjwal', a word before the word ate using regular expression. Can anybody help me with the regex? in python.

Actually I have a list with words like 'ate', 'eat', 'eaten' like in 'Ujjwal had eaten the apple.' Here also Ujjwal should be extracted. How can I check words of the list and not only 'ate' itself ?

Comment: Please update your requirement of matching a list with words in the question.  It often cause some feedbacks when people change the requirement after people post the answer.  However, this situation is not uncommon too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a word list and want to get a regex to match the word list in Python, you can define a pattern with a sub-pattern with `|` (or) and joining the words in word list.  For example:

```
import re

word_list = ['ate', 'eat', 'eaten']

pattern = rf'(\w+)\s*(?:\b(?:{"|".join(word_list)})\b)'

result1 = re.findall(pattern, 'Ujjwal ate the apple.')

print(result1)
# output:
['Ujjwal']

result2 = re.findall(pattern, 'Ujjwal eaten the apple.')

print(result2)
# output:
['Ujjwal']
```

Here, we use r-string together with f-string to hold the pattern.

`{"|".join(word_list)}` in the f-string will resolve to `ate|eat|eaten`, effectively making a regex as `r'(\w+)\s*(?:\b(?:ate|eat|eaten)\b)'`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But one last question if the sentence is 'Ujjwal had eaten the apple'. Means if there is a word had or something, how could we extract.

Comment: @UjjwalMahajan  You can enter 'had eaten' instead of 'eaten' in the word list.  The code already support this.   Alternatively, you have to modify the regex to include an optional `had|has|have` etc. e.g. `rf'(\w+)\s*(?:had|has|have)?\s*(?:\b{"|".join(word_list)}\b)'` but this would be less generic.

Comment: Slightly edited on the placement of boundary anchor `\b` in the regex.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer @SeaBean. And if we have to extract previous 2 words instead of 1, what would be the regex? Actually I'm trying to put {0,2} at places in the regular expression, but it's not working. Kindly help

Comment: @UjjwalMahajan  You can try `pattern = rf'(\w+)\s*(\w+)?\s*(?:\b(?:{"|".join(word_list)})\b)'`.  The result for `re.findall(pattern, 'Ujjwal Mahajan ate the apple.')` will be: `[('Ujjwal', 'Mahajan')]`

Comment: @UjjwalMahajan  What result / error you get ?

Comment: Sorry SeaBean, it was my mistake. Now it worked. Thankyou so much.

Comment: @UjjwalMahajan  You can also use `pattern = rf'(\w+(?:\s*\w+)?)\s*(?:\b(?:{"|".join(word_list)})\b)'`  if you want to extract 2 words as one entry (instead of one tuple of 2 entries). `re.findall(pattern, 'Ujjwal Mahajan ate the apple.')` will be: `['Ujjwal Mahajan']`

Answer (score 1):

For common word (any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_])) you can use

```
import re
results = re.findall('(\w+) ate', 'Ujjwal ate the apple.')
print(results)
```

and the result of `print` is

```
['Ujjwal']
```

**[Edit]**

If you have to check for many words (see comments)

```
list_of_words = ['ate', 'eat', 'had eaten']
results = [re.findall('(\w+) {WORD}'.format(WORD='\\b' + '\\b \\b'.join(word.split(' ')) + '\\b'), 'Ujjwal had eaten the apple.') for word in list_of_words]
print([item for sublist in results for item in sublist])
```

Comment: Actually I have a list with words like 'ate', 'eat', 'eaten' like in 'Ujjwal had eaten the apple.' Here also Ujjwal should be extracted. How can I check words of the list and not 'ate' itself.

Comment: That wasn't your question.  The answer that's been given have answered your question.  If you have a further question you should post an additional one with the further details preferably with a link back to this question explaining it's a follow on question.